# Вызов метода из фонового потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, методы

У меня имеется один класс. Внутри класса есть **два метода**:

1. Метод с бесконечным циклом, - этот метод запускается в отдельном фоновом потоке.
2. Метод, в котором выполняются какие-то любые действия. Предположим, цикл на 1000 итераций.

**Вопрос:** если я в первом методе (в фоновом потоке) вызову второй метод, в каком потоке будет выполняться второй метод? Мне сказали, что он будет выполнен в том потоке, в котором он был вызван, то есть - в фоновом.
Но я не понимаю, почему? Меня очень интересует, где я могу об этом почитать?
Предоставьте, пожалуйста, информацию об этом. Не могу найти в интернете ничего по этой теме.

Comment: Почему метод, по вашему мнению,  должен вызваться в другом потоке?

Comment: Тут смотря как вызовете.
Если обычный вызов метода(Method()), то он будет вызван в том же потоке и вызван синхронно.
Если вызовете Task.Run(() => Method()), то он будет исполняться в другом потоке без ожидания результата.

Comment: Потоку всё-равно функции вы вызываете, методы или просто считаете 2+2, всё выполняется в этом же потоке, если вы в явном виде не переключитесь как-то на другой поток.

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы. Да, я понимаю теперь, что выполняться метод будет конкретно в потоке, в котором был вызван. 
Меня больше конкретно интересует принцип этого. Почему так? Где об этом можно почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть в том, что у каждого потока есть свой стек вызовов. То есть, если мы вызовем метод в каком-то потоке, то выполнятся он будет именно в этом потоке. По-моему, концепция потоков хорошо описана в книге Таненбаума "Современные операционные системы", она поможет разобраться с некоторыми понятиями на более глубоком уровне.